# How to perform hyperparameter tuning on parameters that are part of dataset generation?

Tags: scikit-learn, dataset, hyperparameters

I have a dataset that is the result of numerous "hyperparameters", in the sense that the dataset itself is reliant on specific parameters set at specific values. I would like to be able to optimize these parameters in ML model (e.g. via GridSearch or something similar) and be able to expose these hidden hyperparameters as values that can be searched over. In this case I'm using a `sklearn` pipeline with a `param_grid`

Most tooling out there is solely centered around hyperparamter tuning ***after*** the dataset has been generated, and only changing things relevant to the how the pipeline is defined. But ideally, I'd like to be able to, say, change the lowpass cutoff frequency of one stage of the data generation, and see if that yields a more performant model.

Is there any tooling out there that includes the dataset generation as a part of the pipeline process, and thus we can leverage it to actually set these hidden hyperparameters?

The only thing I've come across that might work is the sklearn [FunctionTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer.html). This seems to allow arbitrary functions, but I worry about duplicated efforts; say hyperparameter A is in the regressor,will the dataset generation happen every time? or does sklearn know how to cache common steps?

Just learning about all of this, happy to have some insight!

Comment: Hello @hobbitmessiah! Did you have the time to try out my answer? Does it help you? If so, please consider [marking it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/1133249). If anything is unclear, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

You can employ a custom transformer and leverage the `memory` parameter of the `Pipeline` in `scikit-learn` to cache transformer outputs.

**Custom Dataset Generator Transformer**

```py
class CustomDatasetGenerator(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, lowpass_cutoff=1.0, another_param=2.0, ...):
        self.lowpass_cutoff = lowpass_cutoff
        self.another_param = another_param
        ...
        
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        # Nothing to do here
        return self

    def transform(self, X=None, y=None):
        # Generate your dataset based on self.lowpass_cutoff, self.another_param, ...
        X_new = your_data_generation_function(self.lowpass_cutoff, self.another_param, ...)
        return X_new
```

**Using memory in Pipeline**

```py
# Create a temporary caching directory
location = 'cachedir'

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('dataset_gen', CustomDatasetGenerator()),
    ('classifier', SVC())
], memory=location)
```

**Hyperparameter Tuning with GridSearchCV**

```py
param_grid = {
    'dataset_gen__lowpass_cutoff': [0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0],
    'dataset_gen__another_param': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
    'classifier__C': [0.1, 1, 10],
    'classifier__kernel': ['linear', 'rbf']
}

# Placeholder dataset
X_dummy = np.empty((100, 1))  # Here, 100 is a dummy number, replace which how many you need.
y_dummy = your_target_generation_function_or_placeholder()  # Depending on how you get/generate your targets

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid, cv=5)
grid_search.fit(X_dummy, y_dummy)

shutil.rmtree(location) # Clear cache
```

When you use `GridSearchCV` (or similar tools) in this way, it will search over the dataset generation parameters as well as the model's hyperparameters. The caching provided by the `memory` parameter will ensure that if the data generation parameters (or any transformer parameters) haven't changed in the grid search, the cached transformed data will be used instead of recomputing everything, which saves time.